# How do I delete an element dragged and dropped

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to delete an element when it is dragged into a Bin (id="list4") but not when dragged into another list.  When dropped I update the database as well.  This is the code I'm using to delete elements dropped into list4.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#list4').length; i++){
    $( '#list4' )[i].remove();
}
```

It deletes the `<ul>` holding the `<li>` elements rather than just the `<li>` elements. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - Added full script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list0, #list1, #list2, #list3, #list4").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectList",
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            var list0 = $( "#list0" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list1 = $( "#list1" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list2 = $( "#list2" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list3 = $( "#list3" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list4 = $( "#list4" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            campaignBoardAJAX(window.JSON.stringify(list0), window.JSON.stringify(list1), window.JSON.stringify(list2), window.JSON.stringify(list3), window.JSON.stringify(list4));
            for(var i = 0; i < $('#list4').length; i++){
                $( '#list4' )[i].remove();
                }
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: You need to add a `drop` event handler on the 'bin' element that deletes the dragged item

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - can you point me to a link explain that please

Comment: That would depend on what drag/drop library you're using. Assuming it's jQueryUI, here's the docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I apologise for being a pain, but should this work?   $( '#list4' ).on( "drop", function (event, ui) {
    this.remove();
});

Comment: Change `this.remove()` to `ui.draggable.remove()`

Comment: That isn't working

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: No errors.  It just leaves the draggable in the Bin

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net that shows this behaviour

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan    sorted it with $('#list4').empty();  Thank you for your help because it got me looking in the right place

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list0, #list1, #list2, #list3, #list4").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectList",
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            var list0 = $( "#list0" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list1 = $( "#list1" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list2 = $( "#list2" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list3 = $( "#list3" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            var list4 = $( "#list4" ).sortable( "toArray" );
            campaignBoardAJAX(window.JSON.stringify(list0), window.JSON.stringify(list1), window.JSON.stringify(list2), window.JSON.stringify(list3), window.JSON.stringify(list4));
            $("#list4").empty() ;
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```